# How to search for a comma separated value

Tags: mysql

Hello i have a string that is stored in my database separated by comma
eg: (new south wales,Queensland,etc,etc)
Know my problem is when i try to search Queensland i am not able to get the result but when i try to search for new south wales i get the record.

But i want to get the result when i try to search for queen or etc.
I am new to php so please help...

Comment: What does your existing query look like? You may be not too far off from the right answer.

Answer (score 7):

## Short Term Solution

Use the [FIND_IN_SET function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('Queensland', csv_column)
```

...because using LIKE with wildcards on either end is risky, depending on how much/little matches (and it also ensures a table scan).  Performance of LIKE with wildcards on either side is on par with REGEXP--that means bad.

## Long Term Solution

Don't store comma separated values -- use a proper many-to-many relationship, involving three tables:

### Things

- thing_id (primary key)

### Australian States

- State_id (primary key)
- State_name

### Things_to_Auz_States

- thing_id (primary key, foreign key to `THINGS` table)
- State_id (primary key, foreign key to `AUSTRALIAN_STATES` table)

You'll need JOINs to get data out of the three tables, but if you want to know things like how many are associated to a particular state, or two particular states, it's the proper model.

Answer (score 3):

Not really what you were asking, but just to be complete: you're going to have a lot of trouble unless you change your approach.

The correct way:

```
TableOne
--------
ThingID


TableTwo
--------
ThingID
Province
```

Then your database query becomes:

```
SELECT fields FROM TableOne WHERE ThingID IN 
    (SELECT ThingID from TableTwo WHERE Province = 'Queensland')
```

And what do you want to have happen when they search for "Australia"? Get back both Western Australia and South Australia?

Comment: +1, not really an answer to the question, but the best solution.

Answer (score -2):

By using `REGEXP`

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP $your_search_string");
```