# Situation with SQL query

Tags: sql

I have data in table in below format

```
id   brand_ids
--------------
2    77,2
3    77
6    3,77,5
8    2,45,77
--------------
```

(Note the brand ids will be stored like comma separated values, this is common for values in this field)

Now i am trying to get a query which is capable of querying out only rows which have '77'
in it..

I know i can use LIKE command in three formats `LIKE '77,%' OR LIKE '%,77,%' OR LIKE '%,77'` with or condition to achieve it. But i hope this will increase the load time of the sql.

is there any straight forward method to achieve this? if so please suggest.

Thanks,
Balan

Comment: I don't know what field you're in where comm-separated, non-normalized columns are common, but the solution here is to store them in a proper normalized table.  This is going to cause nothing but headaches.

Comment: Do you have any index on that "brand_id" column.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852443/how-to-search-for-a-comma-separated-value, Quentin's answer.

Comment: @ Michael : I am working in a Magento database, where this situation occurs. Thanks for your link i got an idea with your link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A strict answer to your question would be: no.  Your suggestion of using LIKE is your best option with this data model.  However, as mentioned, it is highly suggested that you use a more normalized model.